# Selenium on viewer-pdf-toolbar

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium and I want to know if it is even possible to access web-elements in the Chrome PDF toolbar. I don't need to manipulate anything, I just need the . It's buried within shadow dom related stuffs and I'm attempting with a JS executor the following:

```
function recursiveSearch(element, target) {
     let result = element.querySelector(target);
     if (result) { return result; }
     let subElements = element.querySelectorAll('*');
     for (let i = 0; i<subElements.length; i++) { 
         let subElement = subElements[i]; 
         if (subElement && subElement.shadowRoot) { 
             let result = recursiveSearch(subElement.shadowRoot, target);
             if (result) return result;
         }
     }
 }
 return recursiveSearch(document, '#pagelength');
```

(Note, this is stringified for using in the C# executor)

When executing the console for the viewer-pdf-toolbar it actually does work but I can't get it to work in context.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no.